# Unexpected Token Error in Webpack Compilation: Module Parsing Failed

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, qr-code

I am running some tests in Cypress where, in one of the steps, I have to go through the sign-up process, and then it asks me to scan a QR code. For that, I execute the following lines of code to scan the QR code and generate the OTP.

This is what I am trying:

```
import OTPAuth from 'otpauth';
const qrcode =new Decoder();

cy.get('img[alt="QR Code"]').then(image => {
        const src = image.prop('src');
        const decoded = qrcode.scan(src);
        const totp = OTPAuth.URI.parse(decoded.data);
        const generateOTP = totp.generate();
        cy.get('input#code').type(generateOTP);
      })
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/otpauth/dist/otpauth.esm.js 970:28
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (970:28)

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (970:28)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| const randomBytes = size => {
|   {
>     if (!globalScope.crypto?.getRandomValues) {
|       throw new Error("Cryptography API not available");
|     }
 @ ./cypress/e2e/tests/invitation-portal-invitation.cy.js 18:38-56
    at handle (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:212:23)
    at finalCallback (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:306:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:304:22
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:499:39)
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:298:10
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:482:27
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at done (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:464:33
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:143:16
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:143:16
    at /Users/pedro/Library/Caches/Cypress/12.13.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:61:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:23)

This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:

- A missing file or dependency
- A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's working up to the point you try to `URI.parse(decoded.data)`? Can you say what value is in `decoded.data`?

Comment: Or paste a snip of the qrcode?

Comment: decoded is the result of scanning the QR code image using the qrcode library. The decoded object likely contains information extracted from the QR code, and decoded.data refers to a specific property or value within that object.

Comment: and yes, apparently is working until that point

Comment: ***decoded is the result of scanning the QR code***  - yes, but literally what is it? What do you see when you log it?

Comment: The errors appears when I import: 
import * as OTPAuth from "otpauth"; 

I think there should be a problem in the cypress.config.js.

Comment: const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const allureWriter = require('@shelex/cypress-allure-plugin/writer');
const cypressOtp = require('cypress-otp');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  defaultCommandTimeout: 30000,
  requestTimeout: 30000,
  retries: 1,
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      allureWriter(on, config);

      on("task",{
        generateOTP: cypressOtp,
      });
      return config;
    },
  },
  "env": { 
    "allureResultsPath": "allure-results",
    "mailSlurp":"b7a90c6fc50f7ee292fc9fdc0ae6813e8d5c03f4aced93b24f57142adc661ccc"
  },
});

Comment: this is what I am getting when I do a console.log of decoded.data: Decoded data: undefined

Comment: I don't get `undefined` - probably you have wrong image url or image not otp, or maybe typo.

Comment: I think the problem is the OTPAuth library. When I import the library into my test, the error that I mentioned in the description appears. The test does not run when I import it. There is something going on with that library that I don't know what it is.

Comment: import OTPAuth from "otpauth" when I import this library I am getting the error.

Comment: Do I need to configure webpack and babel? do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You made mistake with url or it's wrong image.

Here some sample QRCode for OTP [kcramer/OTPTestCodes.md](https://gist.github.com/kcramer/c6148fb906e116d84e4bde7b2ab56992).

This test works from first example.

```js
import { Decoder } from '@nuintun/qrcode'
const qrcode = new Decoder()

it('test otp qr code', () => {

  const url =
    'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/kcramer/c6148fb906e116d84e4bde7b2ab56992/raw/f8e9708ba72625c1fe404f5eb1388d6ed6d443d6/TOTP-AcmeCo-jdoe@example.com.png'

  const expectedDecode = 'otpauth://totp/ACME%20Co:jdoe@example.com?secret=AUSJD7LZ5H27TAC7NW2IJMATDMVDUPUG&issuer=ACME%20Co&algorithm=SHA1&digits=6&period=30'

  qrcode
    .scan(url)
    .then(result => {
      expect(result.data).to.eq(expectedDecode)  // passing
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
})
```

Comment: think the problem is the OTPAuth library. When I import the library into my test, the error that I mentioned in the description appears. The test does not run when I import it. There is something going on with that library that I don't know what it is. Do I need to configure something to use this library?